# Neo4j query execution process

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j 5.1 Enterprise edition.

I performed the following code:

```
profile MATCH(d:Dataset {name:'dataset2'})<-[:`has_d`]-(s:Score)-[:`has_a`]->(a:Algorithm {name:'algorithm1'})
MATCH (t:Tag) WHERE t.name IN ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5']`
MATCH (i:Image)-[:has_score]->(s)-[:`has_tag`]->(t) 
RETURN i LIMIT 100
```

Due to the profile result is too big, i only post here the important part:
[image]

I was expecting it to filter Tag by name before doing Expand.

Why Neo4j did Expand before Filter?

How can i fix it? Is the order of execution irrelevant?

Is Filter@Neo4j a simple filter or it uses our index?

I'm very sorry for asking so many questions, maybe some of them are stupid and obvious, but I don't understand why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use this and you will see that it will fetch s and t first;  profile MATCH(d:Dataset {name:'dataset2'})<-[:`has_d`]-(s:Score)-[:`has_a`]->(a:Algorithm {name:'algorithm1'})
MATCH (t:Tag) WHERE t.name IN ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5']` WITH s, t MATCH (i:Image)-[:has_score]->(s)-[:`has_tag`]->(t) 
RETURN i LIMIT 100

Comment: You are running 3 MATCH statements without WITH clause so it is doing a cartesian product on it's own

Comment: @jose_bacoy Thanks for your answer. The profile result of your code is exactly the same as mine. So, Neo4j does Expand before Filter. Nothing changed with WITH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to follow the relationships by type and direction first from the source nodes.

So it does the expand by type and direction
and only then sees the end node and then can filter those nodes if they have the matching label(s).

If your relationships are already uniquely identifying the target node label, then you can leave off the labels from those (but not from the start node otherwise it won't use the index).

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me an example? Whatever i did didn't affect the profile plan.